# Google Colab (Jupyter Notebook): Install and import a package from Google Drive

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, setuptools

I want to install and import a package (that I created myself and which is not public) from a google drive into a jupyter notebook. The package works locally and can be imported and used.

Installing the package via jupyter magic works:

```
%pip install /content/drive/MyDrive/mypackage/
[...]
Successfully installed mypackage
```

It completes after successfully installing the package and its dependencies.

But when I try to import the package:

```py
import mypackage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'
```

`pip freeze` shows the dependency but it does not show the package version, but its path:
`mypackage @ file:///content/drive/MyDrive/mypackage`.
Even if I add that path to the sys.path, it does not work.

I am using the free version of Colab, if that matters ( but could upgrade).

What I am doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?